# How to remove MS SQL TOP clause from a query to make it work on SQLite

Tags: c, sqlite

I need to migrate an old program from MS SQL to SQLite through ODBC. I don't have source code. It works perfect while writing the data, but some SELECTs with TOP clause doesn't work. The query string from the executable file is:

```
SELECT TOP %ld [%s] FROM [%s] WHERE ( [%s] < %f )
```

The query is against single field. I need to remove "TOP %ld" part but keep the result. The right query is something like:

```
SELECT "%s" FROM "%s" WHERE ( "%s" < %f )
```

This string is passed to sprintf or similar C function, so I need to have %ld as first parameter, but the result should be the same as first query.

Is there a way to keep %ld without changeing the result while changing the database from MS SQL to SQLite?

EDIT 1: It's a 32 bit Windows application.

EDIT 2:
If I use next string:

```
SELECT "%.*s" FROM "%s" WHERE ( "%s" < %f )
```

I can get very close result, but I lose the requested number of rows. Also if first parameter is less than the count of the characters of the column name there will be SQL exception.

EDIT 3:
Aloso possible:

```
 SELECT ( %ld * 0 ) + "%s" FROM "%s" WHERE ( "%s" < %f )
```

It requires the column to be of number type which is the usual case. The exception from EDIT 2 is avoided.

Comment: If you don't have the source code to your application, what can you change?

Comment: Thank you! Very helpfull. I need to change exactly what I wrote above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a comment:

```sql
SELECT /*%ld*/ [%s] FROM [%s] WHERE ( [%s] < %f )
```

With SQLite 3.8.3 or later, you can use a [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) to get the first value into the LIMIT clause:

```sql
WITH L(x) AS (SELECT %ld)
SELECT [%s] FROM [%s] WHERE [%s] < %f LIMIT (SELECT x FROM L);
```

Comment: The second one looks promissing. Thank you. The first is wrong because of printf parameters (pleas see the edits or Crozin's answer).

Comment: The first one's parameters are identical with those in the original query.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It is commented in SQLite not in C where it still exists.

Comment: Thank you very much. It solves the problem. The first string, because in executable the space for strings is limited by next string. The second one is better, but there is no space for whole string.

Answer (score 0):

If your `printf`-like function supports ordering of attributes you could easily change the query.

```
printf("1 = %2$d, 2 = %1$d", 1, 2); // prints "1 = 2, 2 = 1"
```

So try something like:

```
SELECT %2$s FROM %3$s WHERE ( %4$s < %5$f ) LIMIT %1$ld
```

Comment: I'm not sure. Does VC before 2005 supports ordering?

Comment: I don't believe the programmers are used `printf_p`. But I will check in any case. Visual C++ 2005 supports it.

Comment: Well.. if you don't have access to the sources the easiest way is to simply check what will happen when you replace SQL. ;-)